# Transparency with a mask

Tags: node-editor, masking

I would want to put a mask on a picture with the background transparent. I currently have it in the node editor. I have a mask input node and I add it to my image with a mix node. But I can only set color(like green, red, brown...) with the mix node but I would want a transparent background.

Comment: did you try "Set Alpha" node

Comment: how would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Set Alpha node found in : **Add**➝**Converter**➝**Set Alpha** use the **mask** node  output as an Alpha input for the Set **Alpha node** :

[image]